# Why didn't Shikaku and Inoichi flee to safety?

Tags: naruto

When the HQ came to know about the biju bombs that were headed for them, why didn't they try to flee? It's possible to outrun a biju bomb's blast, as shinobi do cover distances real fast.

[image]
[image: Shikaku and Inoichi before death]

They could have been a valuable asset in the war.

Comment: please only edit to make the question clearer, not because it's not getting enough attention. personally i feel the original title makes more sense because then who is "they" as the only names you ever mention was in the title

Comment: @Memor-X Sorry, but I didn't find any other way to bump my post. And I'm not sure if a bounty would lead to a fruitful result.

Comment: yeh you don't "bump" questions with edits, to draw attention you are supposed to use the bounty system. using edits for the purpose of bumping questions will get you suspended as has occurred to other users in the past on other SE sites

Comment: @Memor-X Oops. Pardon me. What would you say about this though? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Comment: I was simply restating the title to draw more audience. Of course, it was my fault that I forgot to edit the body to include the character's identification, but that's a separate issue.